# Axis OX and OY title in java

Tags: java, graph, draw

I have this piece of code responsible for creating the axis and do not know how and where to implement the titles for the axis. I have a question about the X-axis, because now on the axis is displayed for the smallest and largest value chart looks bad and how do I change it to list the higher and lower values so that the graph would have a "middle" and not on the axes. Thanks for help!

```
 // create hatch marks and grid lines for y axis.
    for (int i = 0; i < numberYDivisions + 1; i++) {
        int x0 = padding + labelPadding;
        int x1 = pointWidth + padding + labelPadding;
        int y0 = getHeight() - ((i * (getHeight() - padding * 2 - labelPadding)) / numberYDivisions + padding + labelPadding);
        int y1 = y0;
        if (scoresY.size() > 0) {
            g2.setColor(gridColor);
            g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding + 1 + pointWidth, y0, getWidth() - padding, y1);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            String yLabel = (getMinScore() + (getMaxScore() - getMinScore()) * ((i * 100.0) / numberYDivisions)) + "";
            // String yLabel = scoresY.get(i) + "" ;
            FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
            int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(yLabel);
            g2.drawString(yLabel, x0 - labelWidth - 5, y0 + (metrics.getHeight() / 2) - 3);
        }
        g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
    }

    // and for x axis
    for (int i = 0; i < scoresX.size(); i++) {
        if (scoresX.size() > 1) {
            int x0 = i * (getWidth() - padding * 2 - labelPadding) / (scoresX.size() - 1) + padding + labelPadding;
            int x1 = x0;
            int y0 = getHeight() - padding - labelPadding;
            int y1 = y0 - pointWidth;
            if ((i % ((int) ((scoresX.size() / 10.0)))) == 0) {
                g2.setColor(gridColor);
                g2.drawLine(x0, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding - 1 - pointWidth, x1, padding);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                String xLabel = scoresX.get(i) + "" ;
                FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(xLabel);
                g2.drawString(xLabel, x0, y0 + metrics.getHeight());


            }
            g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
        }
    }

    // create x and y axes 
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, padding + labelPadding, padding);
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, getWidth() - padding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding);
    Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
    g2.setColor(lineColor);
    g2.setStroke(GRAPH_STROKE);
    for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size() - 1; i++) {
        int x1 = graphPoints.get(i).x;
        int y1 = graphPoints.get(i).y;
        int x2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).x;
        int y2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).y;
        g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    }
    // and for x axis
    for (int i = 0; i < scoresX.size(); i++) {
        if (scores> 1) {
            ...
            if (....) {

                g2.drawLine(x0, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding - 1 - pointWidth, x1, padding);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                String xLabel = scoresX.get(i) + "" ;
                FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(xLabel);
                g2.drawString(xLabel, x0, y0 + metrics.getHeight());


            }
            g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
        }
    }

    // create x and y axes 
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, padding + labelPadding, padding);
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, getWidth() - padding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding);
    Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
    g2.setColor(lineColor);
    g2.setStroke(GRAPH_STROKE);
    for (....) {
        int x1 = ...
        int y1 = ...
        int x2 = ....
        int y2 = ...
        g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    }*/
```